# Logstash locks the Log file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am stashing the log files of database to elasticsearch using Logstash.

When I try to stash the log files, logstash reads the file to process the lines. While reading, logstash locks the file and it does not allow others to make any changes to the content.

Even after all the log lines are read and there are no more lines to read, the file is still locked for logstash and I could not do any changes to the content or add more lines to it.

I can only make changes, when I forcefully stop the service of logstash. Can anyone give me a solution for this issue?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Have you tried running logstash as a `nohup` process? But did you try adding more content while you were running the instance normally ?

Comment: Yes I did try adding more content to the file. But the logstash locks the file preventing any additional data to be added to the file. The message I get when I add more content to the file is "File is being used by another application". I have not tried running the logstash as nohup process.